# Toggle hide UITextField with fixed number of dot

Tags: swift

Currently, i'm using the code below but there is a problem that the last part of the text is `...` instead of `***` (see picture). Now I want to hide text with only six `*` like `******` and figure out how to fix the problem above.

```
@objc func hideMoney(){
        if isMoneyHide == true{
            moneyAmount.isSecureTextEntry = true
        }else{
            moneyAmount.isSecureTextEntry = false
        }
        isMoneyHide = !isMoneyHide
    }
```

The result:

[image]

[image]

Thank in advance

Comment: Your text field isn't wide enough. Fix the width as needed.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue

Set minimum font size to lower than your UITextField text size

Example: - If your UITextField text size is 20 then minimum font size set to 15

[image]